# This is undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I was looking at some react code in my render method and I was wondering why 'this' is undefined ? I am using _this to reference this properly but I dont see why 'this' wouldn't work.

Here is the code:

```
 render: function(){
        var _this = this; 

        function message(){
            console.log('what is this ? ', this); // -> returns undefined!!!!

        }
        return(
            <div>
                <h3> Weather Component </h3>
                <WeatherForm onSearch={this.handleSearch}/> // This 'this' works fine
                {message()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I'm sure this is super easy. I just want to know why im getting undefined.

Comment: When does `message` get called?

Comment: `this` doesn't work because `message` and `render` are *different functions*

Comment: Since you have already created the variable `_this`, then you can use that.

Comment: I got it now thanx. I had to change message to message.call(this);

Comment: @trincot — `message` isn't a property of `this`. It is a variable in the local scope, so no, not `this.message()`.

Comment: Indeed, it is private so that would not work.